# Extrusion provides rounded result

Tags: modeling, extrude

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMwCI.jpg)

I am making a cup handle using extrusion and here when I try to extrude, it provides a sort of rounded cylindrical shape rather than the expected extrusion.

Comment: Your object appears to have a subdivision surface modifier. Enable the edit mode cage, and you will see the modifier in edit mode. Or set the modifier to simple instead of Catmull Clark subdivision.

Comment: You have double geometry, most likely you extruded and then cancelled the translation, causing the 4 new vertices to go back to their origin location. Select everything in edit mode > Right click > Merge > By distance

Comment: Hello, I apologize for the late reply. The merge by distance method works for me, but after an extrusion if I right click it it goes back to the double-geometry mode and I just ctrl+z to bring back the merge by distance, is this normal? Thanks for the help:)